# FOR JSON - How can I create JSON array output without keys?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm playing around with the FOR JSON features in SQL Server 2019, and I'm struggling with how to use that feature to create a JSON list *without* keys... so like just a straight-up list of values.

For example, say I have this SQL:

```
declare @years table (year int)
insert into @years values (2022),(2021),(2020)

 SELECT year
        FROM @years
        FOR JSON AUTO
```

This creates output like so:
`[{"year":2022},{"year":2021},{"year":2020}]`

But how would I get it to create output like THIS instead:
`[2022,2021,2020]`

And I'm looking to do this without messy nested string replaces... but maybe that's the only way? Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([year] int);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (2022),(2021),(2020);

SELECT json = QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG([year], ','))
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| json |
| --- |
| [2022,2021,2020] |

Comment: Note that if `STRING_AGG` returns a value longer than 128 characters, it will be trucates with this solution. This shouldn't be an issue with this example, but it could be with others .

Comment: Sample table and data show INT data type.

Comment: Yes, but `STRING_AGG` returns a string, and *more importantly* `QUOTENAME` expects a `sysname`; so if you have a value returned by `STRING_AGG` that's more than 128 characters, then truncation occurs.